# Why my environment variables are not the same when Pycharm execute the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, environment-variables

**ENVIRONMENT:**

Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7

Python 3.7.13

**PROBLEM:**

My python code needs to execute some terminal commands. But I get the error message: "command not found".

So I tested these same commands from "Terminal" and it worked perfectly.

So I compare the environment variables loaded with my Terminal and the ones loaded with my python script. The result is they are not the same.

You can see here the content of my .zshrc file:

```
export PATH="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home:/Users/alisa/Android/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:/Users/alisa/Android/platform-tools:/bin:/opt/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin/:/usr/bin:/usr/local/opt/qt@/bin/:/usr/local/opt/qt@6/bin/:/Users/alisa/.wdm/drivers/geckodriver/macos/v0.30.0:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home:/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/:/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12_1/bin/:/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages:/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/"
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/alisa/Android"
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home"
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySide2:/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1
set QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1
export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE="$HOME/.mac-ca-roots"
export LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix xz)/lib -L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib -L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix xz)/include -I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(brew --prefix zlib)/include -I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include"
alias python3=/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin/python3
APPDATA="/users/alisa"
export APPDATA

TESSDATA_PREFIX="/opt/local/share/tessdata"
export TESSDATA_PREFIX
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
alias python3="/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9"
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
```

And here the values of environment variables loaded with my python code:

```
HOME:/Users/alisa
LC_CTYPE:en_GB.UTF-8
LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.5_2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/../../../../lib:
LOGNAME:alisa
PATH:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
PWD:/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Phonebot/Phonebot_debug3
PYCHARM_HOSTED:1
PYTHONIOENCODING:UTF-8
PYTHONPATH:/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Phonebot/Phonebot_debug3
PYTHONUNBUFFERED:1
SHELL:/bin/zsh
SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.OJCYKYn5oR/Listeners
TMPDIR:/var/folders/gg/d60v4x454xd_n7dzwkv_y9140000gn/T/
USER:alisa
XPC_FLAGS:0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME:com.jetbrains.pycharm.20596
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING:0x1F5:0x0:0x2
```

You can see the PATH are not the same and so that is why I get the error "command not found".

Here is the Python code I use to display the environment variable:

```
def GetEnvVariables():
    dico_env={}

    for k, v in sorted(os.environ.items()):
        #print(k+':', v)
        dico_env[k]=v
    print(f"dico_env:{dico_env}")
    return dico_env

dico=mymodules.GetEnvVariables()
for key, value in dico.items():
    print('%s:%s\n' % (key, value))
```

I also tried with this command:

```
print(os.environ.get('PATH'))
```

And here is the output:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Again, the PATH value is not the same than my .zshrc file

I am using pycharm to execute my Python code. So I run my code from terminal and this time it worked!
I stopped and restart Pycharm, and I still have same issue.

Does anyone know how can I modify Pycharm to consider all my environment variables?

Thanks

Comment: Are you starting pycharm from your shell or from the launcher? Programs inherit the environment of whatever starts them, so environment variables set by the shell are only visible to things you start from the shell.

Comment: The traditional UNIX approach to fixing this was to have each user's GUI session started by a login shell, but MacOS doesn't follow that approach.

Comment: Relevant question from Unix & Linux: [What should/shouldn't go in .zshenv, .zshrc, .zlogin, .zprofile, .zlogout?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/71253). Note that `.zshrc` is sourced only for interactive shells. It won't be sourced if you run PyCharm from a launcher. For details on shell terminology (login, interactive, ...), see [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38175)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. So I added my values and variable in the file /Users/Alisa/.zprofile. Then I restart the MAC. I relaunch PyCHarm and I still don't get it. So obviously, I should add my environment variables in a 3rd file somewhere?

Comment: There's a plist that launchctl uses to set up the environment variables used by the launcher. It's not really a development-specific problem; you might search [apple.se].

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.zshenv` instead and make sure you restart PyCharm. Works in PyCharm 2022.2.3 Professional.